# Динамический DOM без HTML и CSS

Tags: javascript, оптимизация, dom, производительность

Будет ли страница загружаться быстрее при условии, что мы будем генерировать весь dom через js? По сути у нас не будет html разметки и css кода в файлах, а весь дом будет строиться через js, по сути у нас будет 1 файл забитый js кодом.

Быстрее ли такой подход чем стандартный с файлами html/css?
Желательно развернутые ответы (как, почему и т.д.)

Answer (score 1):

Прежде всего Вы должны думать о пользователях. А пользователи заходя на Ваш сайт хотят одного - увидеть контент, да как можно быстрее. Они не хотят смотреть на белый экран.

Поэтому ответ на Ваш вопрос будет осознание того что Вам дороже - трафик или пользователи.

Если у Вас в `index.html` будет только ссылка на `.js`, то такой файл загрузится быстрее и не удивительно, размер сократился ровно на `.html`. Но генерироваться `dom` будет медленнее и до того момента, как весь файл будет загружен, до момента когда пользователь сможет увидеть контент, будет белый экран.

Альтернатива этому - полноценный `.html`, контент которого пользователь увидит сразу же, как только загрузит `dom` дерево. А скрипты нужно поместить в самый низ `body` для того чтобы начать загружаться после формирования отображения. Но при таком случаи не будет моментального отклика приложения, так как скрипты ещё грузятся, а после загрузки будут выполнятся.

Но лично я склоняюсь ко второму варианту, если рассматривать стандартное вэб приложение.

Answer (score 0):

Неплохой вариант - это делать некий preloader, который будет показывать пользователю более-менее легкий прогессбар или картинку, пока подгружается остальной контент сайта. Для этого достаточно код, стили и скрипт прелоадера поместить выше всего в `index.html`, тогда пользователь даже со слабым интернетом увидит страницу полностью загруженной и не будет расстроен белым экраном и т.д. Вот есть неплохая библиотечка для организации прелоадера, который будет показывать реальный прогресс загрузки [PreloadJS](http://www.createjs.com/preloadjs)

Comment: С прелоадерами надо быть аккуратным. Его использование должно быть  обдуманным. Надо понимать, что посетитель приходит на сайт не смотреть на способности разработчика. И наблюдать вместо контента "крутилки/вертелки" ему не интересно.

Comment: Это конечно понятно, но если размер странички 3+мб, то - прелоадер меньшее зло, чем перекошенная из-за недогрузившегося контента верстка. Чтобы вдохновиться прелоадерами, достаточно в консоли разработчика поставить ограничение скорости загрузки на уровне regular 3g (chrome) и наблюдать пичальку)

Comment: При чем тут вообще прелоадер? Какая еще верстка? читайте топик ребята

Comment: Притом, что, если вы собираетесь организовать динамический дом и управлять загрузкой контента через js - это дает вам возможность управлять этой самой загрузкой и последовательностью отображения загруженного. Что большой плюс и непосредственно относится к вашему вопросу. А вообще современный фронтенд он, конечно с динамическим домом работает, почитайте про reactJs, requireJs